# Java: PropertyResourceBundle

Tags: java

```
public static String fnGetProperty(String ABC)
{
    PropertyResourceBundle configBundle = (PropertyResourceBundle)ResourceBundle.getBundle("ManUtd");
    return configBundle.getString(ABC);
}
```

Please help me to explain the above codes...Thanks ^^

Comment: Which bit of it do you not understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a set of files called `ManUtd.properties` (default language), `ManUtd_fr.properties` (French), `ManUtd_de.properties` (German), (other language versions) etc. [Properties](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) files are a set of key/value pairs; the [ResourceBundle](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) class ensures that the appropriate properties file is used for the current [Locale](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html).

The cast to `PropertyResourceBundle` is a dumb thing to do in my opinion. It should be:

```
ResourceBundle configBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("ManUtd");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the docs ([`PropertyResourceBundle`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PropertyResourceBundle.html)) explain this pretty well. Also, take a look at [`ResourceBundle`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) for the notion of resource bundles.

Answer (score 0):

With the code `PropertyResourceBundle configBundle =(PropertyResourceBundle)ResourceBundle.getBundle("ManUtd");` the ResourceBundle named ManUtd will be searched for on the classpath. Basically if you have a file called ManUtd.properties somewhere on your system, and you include that location on your classpath when you run your program (e.g. java -classpath "path/to/ManUtdFolder") then it will be found and loaded.